# Why do Muslims run slowly in the first 3 Tawaf in Hajj?

Tags: hajj

When muslims go to Umrah they have to perform the tawaf around the Kabah, why does the first 3 have to be at a faster pace? Also why is the Ihraam showing parts of the musculin body?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**why does the first 3 have to be at a faster pace?**

The reasoning behind doing this is to show strength and endurance, and the reason it lives on until today is to commemorate the event behind this as well as to remember the blessings Allah has given us.

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) and his Companions came to Mecca and the fever
>   in Medina had weakened them. Thereupon the polytheists (of Mecca)
>   said: There would come to you a people whom the fever has made weak
>   and they have suffered severely from it. They sat in Hatim. Thereupon
>   Allah's Apostle (ﷺ) commanded them to walk quickly ift three circuits
>   and walk (in four) between the two corners. so that the polytheists
>   should. see their endurance. The polytheists then said (to one
>   anothery You were under the impression that fever had emaciated them.
>   whereas they are stronger than so and so. Ibn Abbas said: He (the Holy
>   Prophet) did not command them (the Muslims) to walk quickly in all the
>   circuits out of kindness to them.

[صحيح مسلم](http://sunnah.com/muslim/15/265)

**Also why is the Ihraam showing parts of the masculine body?**

We do this so that it is more inviting to faster walking, and it livens up the person.  The wisdom behind this, and Allah knows best, is that one should always be ready for Jihad at all times, for one should choose cloths whether in peace or war that would help him work without laziness.

[Source (Arabic)](http://audio.islamweb.net/audio/Fulltxt.php?audioid=134836), [Source (Arabic)](http://www.tohajj.com/Display.Asp?Url=mbr0028.htm)